# Convert strings to data object name and fields

Tags: c#, object

I’m going to get a list from a database consisting of information to pull data from a delimited file and load it into a number of data objects. It'll include the table the data is going into, the data row to look in within the a data file, and the spot in the row to grab.

Right now it’s hard coded as so - TransLevel2.CD_FIELD_1 being a field in a data object on my side:

```
case "SAC":
                    TransLevel2 = new TransLevel2();

                    TransLevel2.CD_FIELD_1 = TryGetString(transLine, 1);
```

(TryGetString being a function to get value x from the row in question from the field, included at request)

```
    public static string TryGetString(string[] transLine, int position)
    {
        return position > transLine.Length - 1 ? string.Empty : transLine[position];
    }
```

So this list would give me TransLevel2, CD_FIELD_1, SAC and 1.

Using the field number is easy:

```
                    int testint=1
                    TransLevel2.CD_FIELD_1 = TryGetString(transLine, testint);
```

The question is, how can I convert the strings TransLevel2 and CD_FIELD_1 into the reference to then load the object?

ADDENDUM - Trying to make myself more clear -

Here's the class I'm trying to assign a value to:

```
public class TransLevel2
{
    public string CD_FIELD_1 { get; set; }
}
```

And the DB call gives me two strings containing "TransLevel2" and "CD_FIELD_1". Those two strings tell me what object (there's a few) and field I need to assign the value to.

So the issue is trying to take those two strings and convert them so I can make the assignment

```
 TransLevel2.CD_FIELD_1 = "tree";
```

So this is effectively what I'm trying to to, but it shouldn't possibly be the only way to do it. For two input strings, and assuming the classes referenced are created:

```
            switch (strobject)
            {
                case "Object1":
                    switch (strfield)
                    {
                        case "field1":
                            Object1.field1 = "tree";
                            break;

                        case "field2":
                            Object1.field2 = "tree";
                            break;
                    }


                    break;

                case "Object2":
                    switch (strfield)
                    {
                        case "field1":
                            Object2.field1 = "tree";
                            break;

                        case "field2":
                            Object2.field2 = "tree";
                            break;
                    }

                    break;


            }
```

Comment: Can you show the method `TryGetString`?

Comment: Included, but it's not really germane to the question. I'm trying to get the two strings for class and field to convert to an actual class and field reference

Comment: I don't understand the problem -- you say I'm loading my object this way and then ask how to load an object.  What exactly is the problem with how you are doing it?

Comment: Attempt at clarification added

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understood your question correctly, you have three strings:

- `strobject`
- `strfield`
- and probably also `strvalue` (hardcoded as `"tree"` in your example),

and you want to

1. create a new object of a type whose name is contained in `strobject`
   and
2. set the property whose name is contained in `strfield` to the value contained in `strvalue`.

This can be done with **reflection**. First, we create the new object instance:

```
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Namespace.Where.Your.Classes.Are." + strobject);
```

then we get the property we need:

```
var propertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperty(strfield);
```

and the we assign the value:

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(o, strvalue, null);
```

---

*(Note: It sounds like you are building a simple [ORM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping). That totally works, and I've done that myself, but if you are just starting, you might want to consider [using an existing product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object%E2%80%93relational_mapping_software#.NET) instead.)*

Comment: Close - it seems to create the object Obj, but when I call
var propertyInfo = Obj.GetType().GetProperty(x.TX_FIELD.ToString());
I see the field in the info in Intellisense.

Do I need to grab the string first? I'm seeing something about unwrapping?

Comment: @VBartilucci: I'm sorry, I don't understand your follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

We have a bingo - Heinzi got me where I needed to go:

```
        ObjectHandle O_810 = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "810");
        Edi810 l_810 = (810)O_810.Unwrap();

        var propertyInfo = l_810.GetType().GetProperty(str);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(l_810, "tree"), null);
```

His code didn't let me get at the types, I apparently needed to unwrap it first.